# Correctly passing parameters containing space, to external program

Tags: bash, sh, ksh

I get some strange behavior when trying to pass script parameters along to an external program, in ksh.

My setup is like this :
- I have a ksh script (called "test"), that boils down to something like this :

```
...
args="$@"
java my_main_class $args
...
```

- If I call this script with something like :

```
> ./test "param1 param2" param3
```

...then the external application sees the following parameters : (param1, param2, param3)

- If I change the script into something like :

  ```
  ...
  java my_main_class "$@"
  ...
  ```

...and do the same invocation, then my external application sees the following parameters (param1 param2, param3) - meaning that now, parameters are correctly seen.

Question : how can I modify my first version of the script, in order to correctly pass the parameters containing spaces, while still storing the "@$" into a variable, before external program invocation ?

Kind regards,
Andrei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's setup the same session:

```
$ set -- "param1 param2" param3
$ echo $1, $2
```

`param1 param2, param3`

ksh and bash offer a valid solution with an array assignment:

```
$ args=("$@")
$ fake_java() { ( for w; do echo "$w"; done ); }
```

This will still fail without quoting:

```
$ fake_java ${args[@]}
```

`param1`

`param2`

`param3`

But quotes and array combined make this work:

```
$ fake_java my_main_class "${args[@]}"
```

`param1 param2`

`param3`

Comment: An older syntax would be `set -A args="$@"`

Comment: Thanks man, this looks like the right thing. Will give it a spin and get back to you.